# bash for loop to check if directory exists

Tags: bash, validation, for-loop, scripting

The following program is just for fun, I am trying to get into bash scripting. I am not going to use the script for doing backups.

I am trying to create a for loop to check if user input (directories that will be backed up) in an array are valid. If input is valid, it should be used. If not, it should be overwritten with a default value `/home/$USER`.

```
echo "Please enter absolute path of directory for backup. Default is "/home/$USER
echo "You can choose multiple directories. Press CTRL-D to start backup."
read USER_DIR

# save user input into array
while read line
do
    USER_DIR=("${USER_DIR[@]}" $line)
done

# check if user input in array is valid (directory exists)
for i in ${USER_DIR[@]}
do
    if [[ -d "${USER_DIR[$i]}" ]]; then
        # directory exists
        ${USER_DIR[$i]}=${USER_DIR[$i]}
    else
        # directory does not exist
        ${USER_DIR[$i]}="/home/$USER"
    fi
done

# show content of array (check if for loop works)
echo "Backups of the following directories will be done:"
for i in ${USER_DIR[@]}; do echo $i; done
```

This is the output I get (`/home/michael/Downloads` is a directory, `notadirectory` isn't)
[image: output bash for loop]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Thank you for the link, it is really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `${USER_DIR[$i]}=${USER_DIR[$i]}` fails.
You should remove the first `$` when you want to assign something.
Your error is earlier.
You want to test the directory `"${USER_DIR[0]}"`, but you are testing `"${USER_DIR[$i]}"`, and this is

```
${USER_DIR["/home/michael/Downloads"]}
```

Try

```
for i in ${#USER_DIR[@]}
```

or

```
for ((i=0; i<${#USER_DIR[@]}; i++))
```

Comment: Thank you, I got confused with how to access positions of an array. At the moment, the script is not working though. It works only if I type in a single directory. Could it be a problem with added special hidden characters after pressing ENTER and typing in the next directory?

Comment: Add ` echo "${USER_DIR[@]}" ` on a lot of places and look where something strange happens.

Comment: I added `echo "${USER_DIR[@]}"` and typed in two valid directories. The script seems to concatenate the input. I typed in `/home/michael/Downloads` two times, and it is displayed as `/home/michael/Downloads /home/michael/Downloads` seemingly with a single whitespace in between.

Comment: I think your answer helped solve an important part of the problem. The first problem is that I seem to not get the input right, as newlines do not seem to be the delimiter, which I would need for my purposes. But it would not have worked anyways, as my loop was not correct. So you helped to solve the problem 50% and I will check your answer as solution. For the other part, I will create a new question, as it is a different problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `echo "${USER_DIR[@]}"` shows all entries, `echo "${USER_DIR[0]}"` shows the first.